# How to pass color in props to change theme?

Tags: react-redux, material-ui, flowtype

Hi i'm trying to pass color: primary or color: secondary to change the color but i dont know how to do it.

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import type { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    width: '80px',
    height: '80px',
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
  colorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
});

export type Props = {
  className?: string,
  classes: { [$Keys<$Call<typeof styles, Theme>>]: string },
  color?: string,
};

const TMPask = ({ classes, className, color }: Props) => (
  <div
    className={classnames(classes.root, className, {
      [classes.colorPrimary]: color === 'primary',
      [classes.colorSecondary]: color === 'secondary',
    })}
  >
    hello
  </div>
);

TMPask.defaultProps = {
  className: undefined,
  color: 'Primary',
};

export default withStyles(styles)(TMPask);
```

i need selectors in the styles const to change between this two themes, i guess that i need like an if condition to get colorPrimary o colorSecondary applied overriding root class, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform it to be the useStyles hook and pass the prop yourself:

```
// @flow

import * as React from 'react';
import makeStylesfrom '@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles';
import type { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    width: '80px',
    height: '80px',
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  colorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

export type Props = {
  className?: string,
  color?: string,
};

const TMPask = ({ color }: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles({color})
  return <div
    className={classes.root}
  >
    hello
  </div>
};

TMPask.defaultProps = {
  className: undefined,
  color: 'Primary',
};

export default TMPask;
```

I am not sure what your `className` does, but I guess it could also be removed now.

The faster way is the accessing of the props directly, since the style object also accepts functions for each value. This allows you to access all props passed to the component. And since your are passing 'color' to it anyway:

```
export const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
    width: '80px',
    height: '80px',
  },
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  colorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: ({color}) => color === 'primary' ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
});
```

Comment: any idea about the return type?

Comment: What do you mean